# Stack algorithm to obtain the greatest number after remove n digits

Tags: c, algorithm, stack

I'm having trouble to implement a stack based algorithm in C to obtain the greatest number after removing n digits from the number.

Basically the problem is:

- given N and a number with k digits, I need to obtain the greatest number after removing n first digits from the given k digit number.
  e.g.: 38271 and 2 => Greatest number is 871.

I achieved doing this with an array implementation, but I'm not achieving to do this using a stack.

Anyone could help me?

**Edit 1: This is my code so far (I'm trying to read a sequence of numbers and get the greatest element of each one of them**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "pilha.h"

void printNGE(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
    int i = 0; 
    struct Stack* stack = createStack(100); 
    stack->top = -1; 
    int element, next; 

    /* push the first element to stack */
    push(stack, arr[0]); 

    // iterate for rest of the elements 
    for (i=1; i<n; i++) 
    { 
        next = arr[i]; 

        if (!isEmpty(stack)) 
        { 
            // if stack is not empty, then pop an element from stack 
            element = pop(stack); 

            /* If the popped element is smaller than next, then 
                a) print the pair 
                b) keep popping while elements are smaller and 
                stack is not empty */
            while (element < next) 
            { 
                printf("n %d --> %d\n", element, next); 
                if(isEmpty(stack)) 
                   break; 
                element = pop(stack); 
            }

            /* If element is greater than next, then push 
               the element back */
            if (element > next) 
                push(stack, element); 
        } 

        /* push next to stack so that we can find 
           next greater for it */
        push(stack, next); 
    } 

    /* After iterating over the loop, the remaining 
       elements in stack do not have the next greater 
       element, so print -1 for them */
    while (!isEmpty(stack)) 
    { 
        element = pop(stack); 
        next = -1; 
        printf("n %d --> %d\n", element, next); 
    } 
} 

int main()
{
   int m;

   scanf("%d", &m); // número de sequências que serão inseridas
   printf("\nsequences: : %d\n", m);

   while (m > 0) {
        char *str;
        char c = '\0';
        int i = 0, j = 1;

        str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

        while (c != '\n') {
            // read the input from keyboard standard input
            c = getc(stdin);

            // re-allocate (resize) memory for character read to be stored
            str = (char*)realloc(str, j * sizeof(char));

            // store read character by making pointer point to c
            str[i] = c;

            i++;
            j++;
        }

        str[i] = '\0';
        printf("\nThe entered string is : %s", str);

        char delim[] = " ";
        char *ptr = strtok(str, delim);
        char *aux[2];

        int x = 0;
        while (ptr != NULL) {
        aux[x] = ptr;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
        x++;
        }

        free(str);

        int tam = strlen(aux[0]);
        printf("\nThe tam is : %d\n", tam);
        char number[tam];

        strcpy(number, aux[0]);
        printf("\nThe number string is : %s\n", number);

        int n = atoi(aux[1]); // converting second parameter passed to integer  
        printf("\nThe splitted number is : %d\n", n);


        int arrayOfNumberDigits[tam];
        for (int l = 0 ; l < tam ; l++) {
            int data = number[l] - '0';
            arrayOfNumberDigits[l] = data;
        }

        printNGE(arrayOfNumberDigits, tam);

        m--;
   }

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} 

**Stack implementation**

stack.c code


#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h> 

#include "pilha.h"

struct Stack* createStack(unsigned capacity) 
{ 
    struct Stack* stack = (struct Stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack)); 
    stack->capacity = capacity; 
    stack->top = -1; 
    stack->array = (int*)malloc(stack->capacity * sizeof(int)); 
    return stack; 
}

int isFull(struct Stack* stack) 
{ 
    return stack->top == stack->capacity - 1; // Se o topo for igual à capacidade, está cheia.
} 

// Stack is empty when top is equal to -1 
int isEmpty(struct Stack* stack) 
{ 
    return stack->top == -1; // está vazia quando o topo é igual a -1
} 

void push(struct Stack* stack, int item) 
{ 
    if (isFull(stack)) // verifica se está cheia, se estiver não é possível adicionar
        return; 
    stack->array[++stack->top] = item; // caso não esteja cheia, adiciona um item no final da pilha e aumenta o topo
} 

int pop(struct Stack* stack) 
{ 
    if (isEmpty(stack)) // checa se está vazia, retornando falso
        return INT_MIN; 
    return stack->array[stack->top--]; // se não estiver vazia, remove o último item e diminui o topo
} 

int peek(struct Stack* stack) 
{ 
    if (isEmpty(stack)) // checa se existe um topo
        return INT_MIN; 
    return stack->array[stack->top]; // se existir, remove o topo
}
```

Comment: Could you share a bit of code to help provide an answer?

Comment: What problems have you encountered? What code have you written so far? If you haven't even written any code yet, how would you solve the problem by hand? What steps does it take to solve the problem? Write these down in words and then try to translate those words into code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
Post the code or logic you used for your existing implementation, and your efforts in extracting the same information in a stack environment.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I edited the question with some code that I did so far

Comment: You've still not explained the problem you're having with the code or asked a specific question related to that code. Your question as currently written reads like a *Here's what I've done. Can you finish my homework for me?* question, and we don't do that here. :-)

Comment: @CaioPardal Thanks for the code example. Now what problem have you encountered with it? What is it doing? Is there an error? If so, what is it? If not what is the output and what do you want it to be instead? I suggest you read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks for your support. I was able to identify my problem and fix my code.